# How do I keep my iPhone 4 flashlight app from blinking when it turns off?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm playing around with a simple little flashlight app that turns on and off the LED flash when you press buttons on my view.

It works just fine, but when I turn off the flash, it blinks once before turning off.  Any ideas what's causing this behavior?

Here's the pertinent code:

```
//
//  No_Frills_FlashlightViewController.m
//  No Frills Flashlight
//
//  Created by Terry Donaghe on 8/9/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Tilde Projects. All rights reserved.
//

#import "No_Frills_FlashlightViewController.h"

@implementation No_Frills_FlashlightViewController

@synthesize AVSession;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)TurnOnLight:(id)sender {
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    AVSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
    [AVSession addInput:input];

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [AVSession addOutput:output];

    [AVSession beginConfiguration];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
    [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
    [AVSession commitConfiguration];

    [AVSession startRunning];

    [self setAVSession:AVSession];    

    [output release];
}

- (IBAction)TurnOffLight:(id)sender {

    [AVSession stopRunning];
    [AVSession release];
    AVSession = nil;
}

- (IBAction)DoNothing:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

AVSession is just a class level AVCaptureSession variable.

And yes, this is code I just found on the internets.  I'm just playing and trying to figure things out.

Comment: Try adding breakpoints at each of the lines in your function that turns off the light and witnessing the behavior from the flash; this way, you can see which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Interesting.  It blinks as soon as I touch the Off button, before the breakpoint (on the first line in the method) is reached.

Comment: is your TurnOffLight method being run directly after the TurnOffLight is run, or are they completely separate?

Comment: Completely separate.  TurnOffLight is an IBAction activated when a button is pressed.

Comment: More interesting.  Just clicking the TurnOffLight button causes blinking whether the light is currently turned on or not.

Comment: I want to make sure your first line in TurnOffLight is not being run before the light blinks. Try adding: NSLog(@"This is a breakpoint"); before [AVSession stopRunning]; and add another breakpoint at the NSLog line. See if the light still blinks when it hits the first breakpoint.

Comment: It blinks off and back on before it gets to the NSLog breakpoint.

Comment: Would you be ok with adding your whole .m file to the original post?

Comment: Try commenting out [output release];. Honestly, I really don't have a clue at this point, sorry man. Right now, my only theory is that there is something wrong with your TurnOnLight method to where the light blinks due to a change in the application's state, which includes simply tapping another button. Actually, why don't you try adding a button to the screen with a method that doesn't do anything (just put an NSLog or something), and seeing if the light blinks when you tap that button. I don't think this has anything to do with the TurnOffLight method at all.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that it has something to do with the AV framework.  I'm guessing that this isn't the optimal code for turning on and off the LED light.  :)  No big deal. Thanks for looking into it. :)

Comment: No problem, glad to at least bring you closer to resolution (:

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but DEFINITELY look into your TurnOnLight code, that's definitely where the problem is, if the light is blinking on the tapping of a button before any of that code even runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on, and it had nothing to do with the code.  :)  ID10T error.

I had copied the "Turn On" button to create the "Turn Off" button.  I forgot to unwire the "Turn Off" button's connection to the TurnOnLight method that was there due to the copying.

I simply removed that connection and now the app works perfectly!  :)

Lesson Learned: Sometimes it's not your source code that's the problem.  :D